# cloud-init error is not working / running my userdata from cdrom iso

Tags: centos6, cloud-init

I am getting the below error-:
[  698.855708] cloud-init[1158]: 2017-10-09 23:48:42,438 - util.py[WARNING]: Broken config drive: /dev/sr0

I am trying to run the cloud-init during boot of VM and to take the iso from cdrom. Its a centos m/c.

Also this error-:
Also this error-:[  846.922986] cloud-init[1158]: 2017-10-09 23:51:10,627 - DataSourceEc2.py[CRITICAL]: Giving up on md from ['http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id'] after 125 seconds
[  847.834620] cloud-init[1158]: 2017-10-09 23:51:10,912 - util.py[WARNING]: Getting data from  failed
[  995.764648] cloud-init[3092]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Tue, 10 Oct 2017 03:53:12 +0000. Up 969.10 seconds.
[ 1080.429808] cloud-init[3507]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Tue, 10 Oct 2017 03:54:49 +0000. Up 1065.33 seconds.
ci-info: no authorized ssh keys fingerprints found for user centos.

PLease suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Above error most likely appears when you have malformed meta_data.json or wrong parameter(s) defined in meta_data.json

See error checking test in cloud-init source:
https://github.com/racker/cloud-init-debian-pkg/blob/409f73b8434717b6a2f0353c605399dde35d1f66/tests/unittests/test_datasource/test_configdrive.py

Check out the test test_seed_dir_bad_json_metadata().